# SSIS ODBC SQL parameters

Tags: sql, parameters, ssis, odbc

I've got a SQL command in an odbc source data flow task that needs to take parameters, but the option to add them isn't there.
I tried to add the database as an ADO.NET connection with an ODBC provider, but there were also no parameters available. Also tried it as an OLEDB connection, but there's no provider available for ODBC.
The variables needed are set, I just can't add them as parameters.

So the main thing I'm wondering are:
Is if there's a way to add parameters to a SQL command in an ODBC source
Is there an OLEDB provider for ODBC I can use?
Can I access the package variables directly in the query? Will that leave me open for a sql injection? Like this.

```
"SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE [id] = " + @[User::id]
```

Edit:
Here's the altered expression

```
"SELECT Name, PhoneNum, Address FROM PERSON<br>
WHERE Name = '" + @[User::Name] + "'<br>
AND PhoneNum = '" + @[User::PhoneNum] + "'"
```

It generates this in the source:

```
SELECT Name, PhoneNum, Address FROM PERSON<br>
WHERE Name = ''<br>
AND PhoneNum = ''
```

Will it fill in the quotes based on the value?

Comment: Did you try looking at using expressions in the connection string?

Comment: The connection string works. Do you mean the sql command from variable option? That doesn't show up in the list of options.

Comment: Sorry I thought you meant parameters in the connection, not the query.

Comment: No problem. I've clarified a bit more in the question.

Comment: I'm gonna try doing this through a script and see how that goes.

Comment: Good luck, I see that ODBC doesn't show up in SSIS until 2012, and I'm still on 2008R2.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to use the expression builder outside the data flow. Go to the control flow tab, select the Data Flow that contains the ODBC or ADO Net Source, and look at the properties window.  You'll see the properties for the ODBC or ADO Net Source there, as well as an "Expressions" property, where you can set the expression to generate your dynamic SQL.

**EDIT**

Here's an image of where you'd change the property. You need to set a generic SQL statement in your data flow, click okay, and go back into the control flow. Then right right click on your data flow and click properties. Under expressions, you can select your SQL command and build it with variables.

[image]

Comment: That would dynamically fill in a variable with the SQL command right? I don't have that option in the ODBC source. Only select from table and sql command.

Comment: @Jooooosh - You're right, it doesn't give you that option. This is a work-around. You'll need to use the property expression editor to create a dynamic sql statement. I've elaborated my answer.

Comment: OK I see what you mean now. The SQL Command property changes the command in the source. Does this look like the correct syntax for the expression? ="SELECT Name, PhoneNum, Address FROM PERSON WHERE Name = " + @[User::Name] + " AND PhoneNum = " + @[User::PhoneNum] + "\""

Comment: I put one that runs in my answer, but it doesn't get any data. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: If it runs, but doesn't return results then it sounds like one of the values for your variables might not be correct. Have you tried removing them and running it? I can take a look at it if that doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah it's the data I'm searching for. Just gotta figure that part out. Thanks for your help. I'll probably be using this a lot.

Comment: I struggled with not seeing the SQL Command property in VS 2017 15.9.14 and SSDT 15.9.2 for about an hour. Eventually it just appeared... Restarted multiple times in between and updated everything. I have no idea what fixed it...