# How to pass variable to sql query of ODBC Source in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using ODBC source in Data flow task of SSIS. I want to select only latest data from ODBC source,

Here is my query:

Select * from ODBCTable
where date >= @[user::date1]

But i am getting error while parsing query.

What is the alternative way this? How can i pass the variable and how to create effective variable to pass the query that can give me only latest today's date data.

Comment: I have defined variable but how can i use ? insted of @[user::date1], how to map these.

Comment: if variable is define then use `?` like `where date >= ?`

Comment: But my variable name is date1, then how i map date1 to ?.

Comment: where you define the variable there is one mapping tab within that map the variable and with your where clause variable and put question mark after equal sign

Comment: I have defined in ssis control flow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS ODBC SQL parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762110/ssis-odbc-sql-parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SQL Command text, first declare your variable then write your sql statement:

```
declare @user_date1 date = cast(? as date)

Select * from ODBCTable where date >= @user_date1
```

Then click on the Parameters button to map an SSIS parameter value to your sql variable.  The mapping is done in order of appearance in your SQL Command - not by name.

Answer (score 2):

You can do in this way create one variable query
then form your query there with parameter .
[image]

[image]

then goto dataflow properties , in expression select ODBC source.sqlcoomand and pass that variable here.

On first run will replace source query with  the expression sql command.
Thanks